# How do I group an array of objects by subobject?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, grouping

I'm using TypeScript for the back-end of a web app, and I've found the intersection types quite useful for making efficient SQL queries. Basically, if I have the following tables:

```
User

userId: number
userEmail: string

Post

postId: number
userId: number (FK)
postBody: string
```

I can end up with an intersection type (User & Post) that looks like this:

```
{
  userId: number;
  userEmail: string;
  postId: number;
  postBody: string;
}
```

This means I can use this type to represent the rows I get back from a joined select query.

The problem is that I have to then pull apart the data in the web server. I have to write iterative code to group them for every query, and this can get repetitive. Here's the kind of transformation I'm trying to get:

In:

```
[
  {
    userId: 1,
    userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
    postId: 1,
    postBody: 'User 1\'s first post',
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
    postId: 2,
    postBody: 'User 1\'s second post',
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    userEmail: 'user2@email.com',
    postId: 3,
    postBody: 'User 2\'s first post',
  },
]
```

Out:

```
[
  {
    userId: 1,
    userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
    posts: [
      {
        postId: 1,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s first post',
      },
      {
        postId: 2,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s second post',
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    userEmail: 'User 2\'s email',
    posts: [
      {
        postId: 3,
        postBody: 'User 2\'s first post',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to come up with a function I can use to do this dynamically, perhaps passing in the collection, an array of parent key names, and the name of the child collection. I ended up with an unsuccessful function with the following signature: `function group(coll: Array<any>, parentKeys: Array<string>, childCollName: string): Array<any>;`

I was wondering if anybody could help me out with implementing this.

So far, I've already tried using Lodash. However, its `groupBy` function doesn't seem to be able to tell that the subobjects are equal and it still gives me an array of three objects in this example.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like below, going in loop and creating objects

```js
var arry = [
    {
        userId: 1,
        userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
        postId: 1,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s first post',
    },
    {
        userId: 1,
        userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
        postId: 2,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s second post',
    },
    {
        userId: 2,
        userEmail: 'user2@email.com',
        postId: 3,
        postBody: 'User 2\'s first post',
    },
];

function createPost(obj) {
    post = {};
    post.postId = obj.postId;
    post.postBody = obj.postBody;
    return post;
}
function convert(array) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var currentObject = array[i];


        if (!map[currentObject.userId]) {
            obj = {}
            obj.userId = currentObject.userId;
            obj.userEmail = currentObject.userEmail;
            obj.posts = [];

            map[obj.userId] = obj;

        }
        obj.posts.push(createPost(currentObject));
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(map);
    return keys.map(function (v) { return map[v]; });
}
var r = convert(arry)
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to achieve the goal.

```js
var source =
    [
    {
        userId: 1,
        userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
        postId: 1,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s first post',
    },
    {
        userId: 1,
        userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
        postId: 2,
        postBody: 'User 1\'s second post',
    },
    {
        userId: 2,
        userEmail: 'user2@email.com',
        postId: 3,
        postBody: 'User 2\'s first post',
    },


]


var grouped = source.reduce(function(v,k){
    if (!v[k.userId]) {
        v[k.userId]={};
    }
    var group = v[k.userId];
    group.userId=k.userId;
    group.userEmail=k.userEmail;
    if(!group.posts){
        group.posts=[];
    }
    group.posts.push({postId: k.postId,
        postBody:k.postBody})
    return v;
},{})

var dataArray = [];
for(var o in grouped) {
    if (grouped.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
        dataArray.push(grouped[o]);
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray,null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take with reduce, some and destructuring

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/Pickra/pen/OOzzoQ?editors=0011)

```
const grouped = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
    postId: 1,
    postBody: 'User 1\'s first post',
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    userEmail: 'user1@email.com',
    postId: 2,
    postBody: 'User 1\'s second post',
  },
  {
    userId: 2,
    userEmail: 'user2@email.com',
    postId: 3,
    postBody: 'User 2\'s first post',
  }
];

const sorted = grouped.reduce((acc, nxt) => {
    const { userId, userEmail, ...rest } = nxt;
    let index;
    let user;

    const accHasUser = acc.some((obj, i) => {
        if (obj && obj.userId === userId) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    if (!accHasUser) {
        user = { userId, userEmail, posts: [rest] };
        acc.push(user);
    } else {
        acc[index].posts.push(rest);
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```